# How to run columnSimilarities after RDD groupBy

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

I used KMeans to split my items into a set of clusters and then inside each cluster, I would like to calculate cosine similarity. 
Unfortunately, IndexedRowMatrix accept only an RDD and as far as I know, it is not possible to run RDD inside another RDD

```
val df =   ...
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(10).setSeed(1L)
val model: KMeansModel = kmeans.fit(df)
val predictions = model.transform(df)

val clusters = predictions.groupByKey(row => row.getInt(0))
clusters.mapGroups {

  case (key, cluster) =>
    ...
    val indexedRowMatrix = new IndexedRowMatrix(....) // How to pass an RDD to build IndexedRowMatrix
    indexedRowMatrix.toBlockMatrix().transpose.toIndexedRowMatrix().columnSimilarities()
}
```

Any idea how how can calculate cosine similarity after grouping by key?

Comment: `@` works if and only if user is already active in a discussion. No point of `@` users otherwise. And as you already know you cannot use `IndexedRowMatrix` in the task. If data is small you can use local data structures, like breeze matrices.

Comment: @user8371915 the data are not small, it is millions of items, so I wish to split into a set of clusters and calculate similarities in each cluster separately and hence reduce the calculation and be able to scale more